# Proving whether or not this limit exists

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

We're given the function $f(x,y) = \frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}$.

We're interested in determining whether $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}{f(x,y)}$ exists.

Clearly the function is not continuous at (0,0). Approaching along the x and y axes gives a limit of 0 in both cases.

I'm struggling to find a relationship between x and y which gives me a different limit. Any help would be much appreciated.

For the record, I tried $x=y$, $x^2 = y$, $x=y^2$ and $x=1/y$, and none of them gave a limit which wasn't 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That limit exists and it is equal to $0$, since $\lvert x\rvert,\lvert y\rvert\leqslant\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and therefore$$\left\lvert\frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right\rvert\leqslant3\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}^3}{x^2+y^2}=3\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$So, given $\varepsilon>0$, take $\delta=\frac\varepsilon3$ and then$$\bigl\lVert(x,y)\bigr\rVert<\delta\implies\left\lvert\frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right\rvert<\varepsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

Take polar coordinates
 $$r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

$$x=r\cos{t}$$ $$y=r\sin{t}$$

The limit of $f(r,t)$ is zero, as $r \to 0$ and independent of the choice of $t$.

So $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}f(x,y)=0$

Answer (score 0):

Easier
$$0\le |f(x,y)|\le \left|\frac{3x^2y}{x^2+y^2}\right|=3|y|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\le 3|y|.$$

Hence, by the Sandwich rule, your limit is 0 (as $(x,y)$ goes to 0).

The nex inequalities are very interesting in these cases:
$0\le\dfrac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\le 1\qquad 0\le\dfrac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}\le 1 \qquad \dfrac{-1}{2}\le \dfrac{xy}{x^2+y^2}\le\dfrac{1}{2}$